snakemake: MissingOutputException in rule hifiasm in file /home/usr/path/to/Snakefile, line 13
Hi there I was working on a very basic Snakemake file to run hifiasm; it seems to work well but, for some reason, at the end of the run I was prompted with the following:

Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files. MissingOutputException in
rule hifiasm in file /home/usr/path/to/Snakefile, line 13: Job
1  completed successfully, but some output files are missing. Missing
files after 5 seconds. This might be due to filesystem latency. If
that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with
--latency-wait: INLUP00233.asm (missing locally, parent dir not present) Shutting down, this might take some time. Exiting because a
job execution failed. Look above for error message Complete log:
.snakemake/log/2024-08-21T144851.077767.snakemake.log WorkflowError:
At least one job did not complete successfully.

This is the code I've been running; does anyone has an explanation on why this is happening? Thanks in advance!
#####################################
#   SNAKEMAKE PIPELINE — assembly   #
#####################################

SAMPLES = ['INLUP00233']

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}.asm", sample=SAMPLES)

rule hifiasm:
    input:
        hifi="{sample}.fastq.gz",
        hic1="{sample}_1.fq.gz",
        hic2="{sample}_2.fq.gz"

    output:
        "{sample}.asm"

    threads: 16

    shell: 
        "hifiasm -o {output} --h1 {input.hic1} --h2 {input.hic2} {input.hifi} -t {threads}"


after you run this pipeline, is INLUP00233.asm created, can you find it in your working dic.?

@kEks no it is not. However, the multiple files generated by the assembler all with prefix INLUP00233.asm are correctly created; the INLUP00233.asm is meant to be just a string in those files' name.

I am not familiar with hifiasm, and just had a quick look at its doc. If I understand you and the doc correctly, you never expected INLUP00233.asm to be created, right?
Because, snakemake is looking for this file, waits, and than tells you "something went wrong" because the output you defined is not created. If you know which suffixes (e.g. ".ovlp.source.bin") are created you could just adapt your rule as below
output:
    "{sample}.asm.ovlp.source.bin"

Those files could than again be the input for a potential subsequent rule.

I see. Much appreciated, I'm familiar with the conventional Bash pipeline but was attempting to converting it all to a Snakemake. This is the first step, I will need several outputs from Snakemake; I guess I can list them separated by comma as per the inputs, right?

yes, same syntax as for the input. Actually, as both inputs. so either with comma and you list them as in you hifiasm rule, or you could also use the expand command as in your all rule. I guess its personal preference.
You would definitely need to include those files which are need by subsequent rules, if you include the others is up to you (The advantage of including all is that, snakemake would tell you if hifiasm, stumbles on its way.

I'll add that you should try to include all files.  There are some pathological cases that will be properly handled only if snakemake is aware of all the expected outputs.  E.g. a command makes files a and b but you only list a.  If a is created but the command fails, snakemake may not realize it (depending on the command exit code).  If b is partially created, the command may try to reuse it on subsequent runs.  In either case, listing all output files allows snakemake to detect and clean up after some errors.
